# How can I direct node.js callback to a non-anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my working simple sample example:

```
function some_function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    var my_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() *
        (arg1 - arg2) + arg2);
    callback(my_number);
}

some_function(5, 15, function(num) {
    console.log("callback called! " + num);
});
```

I'm trying to not use the anonymous function.  This is my attempt which errors:

```
function some_function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    var my_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() *
        (arg1 - arg2) + arg2);
    callback(my_number);
}

some_function(5, 15, some_other_function(num));

function some_other_function(theNumber){
    console.log('printing number: ' + theNumber);
}
```

Is this even possible?  If so, how?

Comment: `some_function(5, 15, some_other_function);` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `callback(my_number);` will call `some_other_function` with the argument `my_number`.

You were very close.

```
function some_function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    var my_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() *
        (arg1 - arg2) + arg2);
    callback(my_number);
}

some_function(5, 15, some_other_function);

function some_other_function(theNumber){
    console.log('printing number: ' + theNumber);
    document.write('printing number: ' + theNumber);
}
```